# NoMethodError in Users#show / undefined method `friendships' for #<Profile:0x007ff052f60b68> Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many

I can´t really figure out why I´m getting this error....Earlier today this was working fine, then I did some modifications that I clearly lost track off,  and now when I start up my App I always get this error when I try logging in as a user.

```
NoMethodError in Users#show
undefined method `friendships' for #<Profile:0x007ff052f60b68>
```

I have 3 Users in my App and they do all have Profiles.

On current_user Profile page the user is able to see his friends and click on their names to see their profile.

Can anyone help me with this?
TIA Dadi

In views/users/show.html.erb

```
<h4> <%= current_user.profile.name%> Friends</h4>
         <ul>
           <% @user.friendships.each do |friendship| %>
           <li>
           <%= link_to user_profile_path(user), :method => :get do %>
           <%= friendship.friend.profile.name %>
           <%#= link_to compare_friends_path(@user), :method => :get do %>
           <%#= friendship.friend.profile.name %>
           (<%= link_to "remove friend", friendship, :method => :delete %>)
           </li>
          <% end %>
          <% end %>
         </ul>
```

In users_controller.rb

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id]).profile

end
```

In user.rb model

```
has_many :friendships
has_many :friends, through: :friendships
has_many :inverse_friendships, :class_name => "Friendship", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
has_many :inverse_friends, through: :inverse_friendships, :source => :user

has_one :profile
```

In profiles_controller.rb

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    #@profile = @user.profile

end
```

In profile.rb model

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user

end
```

In friendship.rb model

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :friend, :class_name => 'User'

end
```

In routes.rb

```
   Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
  resources :users do
  resource :profile
   end

  resources :friendships
 end
```

**EDITED**

in the same view I´m linking to the same route and it works, why is that? I mean this is basically the same link? (see below)

```
          <h3>followers <%= current_user.profile.name%> </h3>
         <ul>
          <%  @user.inverse_friends.each do |user| %>
          <%= link_to user_profile_path(user), :method => :get do %>
            <li><%= user.profile.name %></li>
          <% end%>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id]).profile
end
```

This seems wrong, as you're assigning `User.profile` to `@user`.

This would explain the error `undefined method 'friendships' for #<Profile:0x007ff052f60b68>` as your `User` model has `has_many :friendships`, but `Profile` doesn't.

Note: Using [web_console](https://github.com/rails/web-console) or [better_errors](https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors) can really help track down problems like this and is well-worth spending some time setting up. You get a Ruby console in your browser on an exception, and just typing `@user` would have told you this is a `Profile` instance, and not a `User` instance.

> I did some modifications that I clearly lost track off

Another lesson: Change as little as possible, **TEST**, change as little as possible, **TEST**, and keep repeating this. That way, if something breaks you know exactly which changes caused the error. Keep this feedback loop as short as feasible. This is also something where tools such as `better_errors` really help.

For a more in-depth explanation, see [Feedback Loops in Software Development](http://lethain.com/feedback-loops-in-software-development/).

Comment: hi @Carpetsmoker,  You´re right... when I remove the .profile the error msg changes to     "undefined local variable or method `user' for #<#  <Class:0x007ff053d3a4c8>:0x007ff054110c28>"       "<%= link_to user_profile_path(user), :method => :get do %>"

Comment: @DaðiHall I think you want `@user` there, for the class variable, and not `user` for a local variable, which doesn't exist. That's what the error says: `undefined local variable or method`.

Comment: thank you @Carpetsmoker this is helpful, I edited the question and added other link to the same path which works fine, It´s the same link basically

Comment: @DaðiHall IIRC `user_profile_path(user)` doesn't check if the passed object is actual an instance of `User`, it just grabs the `id` of whatever object is passed to make a link like `/user/42` (i.e. duck typing an all that). If every `User` always has one `Profile` then the ids are probably the same; but this is no guarantee! So you need to use `user_profile_path(user.profile)`.